# How can I extract Time from this string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, time, regex-group

I have this String

```
var data = "Mon 08:30am - 04:30pm"
```

and I need it in this form

```
//expected String remove am pm and convert pm timing into 24 hrs time format
Result = 8:30-16:30
```

How Can I do it with Regex in Javascript .I tried it using substring but thats not the correct way.

I tried it with this but didnt find this correct way

```
var amHourFrom = parseInt(details[0].data.substring(4, 2)));    
var amMinuteFrom = parseInt(details[0].data.substring(7,2)));   
var pmHourFrom = parseInt(details[0].data.substring(14, 2)));   //04
var pmMinuteFrom = parseInt(details[0].data.substring(17,2)));  //30

if(details[0].data.substring(19,2)=="pm"){
{pmHourFrom = hourFrom +12;     //04+12 = 16    
}
var Str= amHourFrom + ":" + amMinuteFrom "-" + pmHourFrom+ ":" + pmMinuteFrom;
var result = Str.replace(/^(?:00:)?0?/, '');
```

I want to do it with some other way

Comment: You are using .substring() incorrectly: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Comment: `"Mon 08:30am 04:30pm".match(/(\d\d:\d\d)/gm)` result in : `(2) ['08:30', '04:30', index: 4, input: 'Mon 08:30am 04:30pm', groups: undefined]`. You then simply retrieve [0] and [1] from the result to get the hours. And then you will have to do the convertion to 24h format

Comment: @Lk77 Can you format it in code please

Comment: Please do not put the java tag on your JavaScript question. JavaScript and Java are vastly different languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try the following regex replacement approach:

```js
var data = "Mon 08:30am - 04:30pm";
var times = data.replace(/(\d{2}):(\d{2})([ap]m)/g, (m, x, y, z) => z === "am" ? x + ":" + y : "" + (12 + parseInt(x)) + ":" + y)
                .match(/\d{2}:\d{2}/g)
                .join("-");
console.log(times);
```

The first chained call to `replace()` converts the hours component to 24 hour time by adding 12 hours in the case of `pm` times.  Then we find all time matches, and join together by dash in the final string output.

Comment: Hi, can you help in extracting from this string as well. "var data= Sun Closed". I need to store Sun and Closed in two different variables.

Comment: The string is like this var data = "Sun Closed", Sorry I put the quotes incorrectly, you misunderstood it my bad

Comment: Use: `data.split(" ")`

Answer (score 1):

I have no easy and short solution for the addition of 12 at the moment but to convert the data with Regex you can use this

```
var result = data.replace(/[^0-9:-]/g, "");
```

This replaces all characters with nothing except the letters in brackets.

Comment: Hi, can you help in extracting from this string as well. var data= "Sun Closed". I need to store Sun and Closed in two different variable

Answer (score 0):

1. As days will always be three characters in length, you can simply slice the string from index 4 (space after the `day` name).
2. Split the string with `-`.
3. Then simply convert the time by passing time one by one and then join them with `-`.

Here is the demo-

```js
var data = "Mon 08:30am - 04:30pm"
var time = data.slice(4).replace(/ /g, '').split('-');

const convertTime = timeStr => {
   const time = timeStr.match(/\d+\:\d+/g).join("")
   const modifier = timeStr.match(/[a-z]+/gi).join("");
   let [hours, minutes] = time.split(':');
   if (hours === '12') {
      hours = '00';
   }
   if (modifier.toLowerCase() === 'pm') {
      hours = parseInt(hours, 10) + 12;
   }
   return `${hours}:${minutes}`;
};

let value1 = convertTime(time[0]) + " - " + convertTime(time[1])
console.log(value1)
```

If the string is dynamic, please, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to stick with your current implementation (which works, just has various bugs within the code), here is a working version:

```
    var data = "Mon 08:30am - 04:30pm";

    var amHourFrom = parseInt(data.substring(4, 6));    
    var amMinuteFrom = parseInt(data.substring(7,9));   
    var pmHourFrom = parseInt(data.substring(14, 16));  
    var pmMinuteFrom = parseInt(data.substring(17,19));  

    if(data.substring(19,21)=="pm"){
        pmHourFrom += 12;
    }
    var str= amHourFrom + ":" + amMinuteFrom + "-" + pmHourFrom+ ":" + pmMinuteFrom;
```